# PDF Files from database keep getting corrupted

Tags: php, sql-server, phpmailer

So I am storing my files in a database. Don't ask why, just know that I am not in control of this. Next, I am able to successfully store them as a hexidecimal representation and then spit them back for display with no problem, but then I attach them to an email using PHPMailer and they get sent properly with the right name and all, but they are corrupted. I will walk you through step by step below so that you know exactly how it is being stored, and this may help me debug my issue. (Please note that all code is paraphrased to save space and only show what is needed)

**STEP 1**

File is grabbed and then processed

```
$name = $_FILES['file_data']['name'];
$file = prepareImageDBString($_FILES['file_data']['tmp_name']);
$mime_type = $_FILES['file_data']['type'];
```

name, file, and mime_type are stored

here is the function `prepareImageDBString()`

```
function prepareImageDBString($filepath){
    $out = 'null';
    $handle = @fopen($filepath, 'r');
    if($handle){
        $content = @fread($handle, filesize($filepath));
        $content = bin2hex($content);
        @fclose($handle);
        $out = $content;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

**STEP 2**

When the file is being viewed I show it as an embedded object. This file is small so I just posted the whole code. Do note that the file shows up with no problems here.

```
$q = "SELECT lease_doc_file_data FROM lease_doc_file WHERE lease_doc__id ='".$_GET['id']."'";
$file = "";
foreach($CONN->query($q) as $row){
    $file = $row['lease_doc_file_data'];
}
if(!empty($file)){

    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    echo hextobin($file);
}
```

Here is the function `hextobin()`

```
function hextobin($hexstr){ 
    $n = strlen($hexstr); 
    $sbin = "";   
    $i = 0; 
    while($i < $n){       
        $a = substr($hexstr,$i,2);           
        $c = pack("H*", $a); 
        if ( $i == 0 ){ $sbin = $c; } 
        else { $sbin .= $c;} 
        $i += 2; 
    } 
    return $sbin; 
}
```

**STEP 3**

Finally the part where I go to send it as a mailer.

```
$q = "SELECT lease_doc_file_data, lease_doc_file_name, lease_doc_file_type FROM lease_doc_file WHERE lease_doc__id ='$id'";
$file_data = "";
$file_name = "";
$file_type = "";
foreach($CONN->query($q) as $row){
    $file_data = $row['lease_doc_file_data'];
    $file_name = $row['lease_doc_file_name'];
    $file_type = $row['lease_doc_file_type'];
}
$file_data = hextobin($file_data);
$mail->AddStringAttachment($file_data, $file_name, 'binary', $file_type);
```

So this is the three step process and I"m not sure where the error is coming from. Hopefully someone can help! Thank you for all help in advance!

Comment: Why is there no STEP 2?

Comment: It's a posting error hold on please

Comment: @LuisÁvila I have finished the post, I don't know how that got submitted like that but I do apologize

Comment: did you try simply: `$mail->AddStringAttachment($file_data, $file_name, 'base64', 'application/pdf');` ?

Comment: yes it still was corrupted

Comment: Why do you use PHP's function `bin2hex` and made your own `hextobin` instead of using PHP's function `hex2bin`?

Comment: I can't remember the reasoning behind it, but it has something to do with how it was being entered and retrieved from the database

Comment: *Hm...* is that column the right type and big enough to hold that binary data? Might be data loss somewhere. Maybe during the uploading.

Comment: As per what I found here http://wp-a2z.com/oik_api/phpmaileraddstringattachment/ that guy's using 5 parameters `$void = PHPMailer::addStringAttachment( $string, $filename, $encoding, $type, $disposition );` - *"( string ) optional default: attachment – Disposition to use"* - Not sure if that would help.

Comment: There's no need to hex encode binary values in the DB. Just use a binary blob field and escape the binary data. When retrieving it you don't need to do any decoding. Your transfer encoding should be `base64`, not `binary`. You don't show what you mean by 'corrupted', i.e. you need to show us how it appears in the received message. @Fred, `addStringAttachment` has 5 params, but some are optional, [as the docs say](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment).

Comment: @Synchro Duly noted. I thought it *"might"* have helped the OP. It's already been suggested about using base64 amongst other things and I think you're *"bang on"* with what you said.